# Give value of for loop to function d3

Tags: javascript, for-loop, d3.js

I'm trying to give a value of a for loop to a on click function of d3. Without any success unfortunately. Does any of you know how to solve this? This is the piece of code in question:

```
function generateLegenda(catlist) {
for (z=0; z < catlist.length ; z++) {

    var legenda = d3.select("div.legendaCats")
                    .append("p")
                    .attr("class", "legendaItem")
                    .on("click", function(d, z){
                        blueLine = catlist[z];

                        // Determine if current line is visible
                        var active   = (d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine)).active ? false : true,
                          newOpacity = active ? 0.2 : 1;

                        // Hide or show the elements
                        d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine).style("opacity", newOpacity);
                        d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine).style("opacity", newOpacity);

                        // Update whether or not the elements are active
                        (d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine)).active = active;
                       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Giannis mentioned, the `z` param of your function override the `z` of the for-loop.
But you have to use a closure, to save the current value of `z` in the listener, try this :

```
function generateLegenda(catlist) {

    for (z=0; z < catlist.length ; z++) {

        var legenda = d3.select("div.legendaCats")
          .append("p")
          .attr("class", "legendaItem")
          .on("click", (function(catIndex){
              return function(d){
                    blueLine = catlist[catIndex];

                    // Determine if current line is visible
                    var active   = (d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine)).active ? false : true,
                      newOpacity = active ? 0.2 : 1;

                    // Hide or show the elements
                    d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine).style("opacity", newOpacity);
                    d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine).style("opacity", newOpacity);

                    // Update whether or not the elements are active
                    (d3.selectAll("#" + blueLine)).active = active;
              };
         })(z));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your mistake is in this:

```
.on("click", function(d, z){
    blueLine = catlist[z];
```

Defining `z` in the function will give a different meaning to it than the value of the for iteration. Try the following:

```
.on("click", function(d){
    blueLine = catlist[z];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! However, when I do this, I get the number '9' (the last item of the list). I want to have, for every item, that it gets the position in the list. Do you have any idea how I can fix that?